# How to load and pass a model to an ascx control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a nestedGridTemplate which contains one object of a list.

```
            this.Gridparent.MasterTableView.NestedViewTemplate = new Custom14NestedTemplate(this.model.Material.First());
```

This calls my class `public class Custom14Template`.

This class calls :

```
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        var myPage = new Page();
        Control c = myPage.LoadControl("~/Custom14/Templates/View.ascx");
        container.Controls.Add(c);

        var x = new Label();
        x.Text = string.Format("qty : {0}.<br />", this.MyMaterial.Quantity);
        container.Controls.Add(x);
    }
```

Right now, my ascx contains only this :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View.ascx.cs" Inherits="*snip*.Templates.View" %>

hello there
```

Everything is displayed correctly

```
  [grid start]
  [item 1 : expanded]
     hello there qty : 23.
  [/item 1]
  [item 2 /]
  [item 3 /]
  [/grid]
```

I'd like to pass my object to my ASCX, to build my html display from there using... The *old* equivalent of `<%= html.EditorFor() %>` (Asp.Net MVC). Instead of creating elements like my label and adding them to the container (building html in c# feels painful). Is that doable? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246082/transfer-value-to-dynamically-loaded-web-user-control) to my need (no *ICustomControl*) :

The calling file contains the following :

```
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {

       Page myPage = new Page();
       Control userControl = myPage.LoadControl("~/Templates/Edit.ascx");

       //this is the important part
       if (userControl is Edit)
       {
           Edit customControl = userControl as Edit;
           customControl.MyObject= this.PersistedObject;
       }

        container.Controls.Add(userControl);
    }
```

The .ascx.cs was also modified a bit :

```
public partial class Edit : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public Produit MyObject { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.product.Text = MyObject.ProductName;
        this.Production.Text = MyObject.Production.ToString();

    }
}
```

And the ascx just contains two plains, regulars asp:textbox (ID= product and production).

Answer (score 0):

Try solution at http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/ "Loading Dynamically".  Easy solution to pass variable information or set properties in user control

Comment: You should summarize or quote a linked article, because links tend to decay over time.